# error when trying to create a php8 iis nano-server docker image

Tags: iis, dockerfile, command-line-interface, php-8, nano-server

i am trying to create a nanoserver-iis-php8 docker image.
when copying the instructions in [php site](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.manual.php)
to a docker file like this line
**RUN powershell -command c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/fastCGI /+[fullPath='c:\php\php-cgi.exe']**
i get this error message when building the image:

ERROR ( message:Malformed collection indexer; format is [@position,name='value',name2='value2',...].  The @position specifier is optional, and be '@start', '@end', or '@N' where N is a numeric index into the collection. )

how do i fix this?

Comment: What is the basic image you used?

Comment: nanoserver/iis i tried to edit the config file (applicationhost.config) myself but i get a service unavailable error when trying to run the image as web server

Comment: This command line looks ok, but there may be something we didn't notice somewhere, you can try to copy the command below and try again to see if it is the same problem. `C:\>%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/fastCGI /+[fullPath='c:\{php_folder}\php-cgi.exe']`

Comment: tried it but still getting a non zero code when building .. maybe a different approach will be better, like updating the config files directly, instead of via cli?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the C# code:

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
  {
     Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();

     ConfigurationSection fastCgiSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/fastCgi");
     ConfigurationElementCollection fastCgiCollection = fastCgiSection.GetCollection();
     ConfigurationElement applicationElement = fastCgiCollection.CreateElement("application");
     applicationElement["fullPath"] = @"C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe";
     serverManager.CommitChanges();
  }
```

Comment: i am new to docker, how do i write the instruction to run the c# code in the dockerfile?

Comment: I am not familiar with docker, you can go to the docker related forum for consultation.